Flutter media_kit: Always show play button or `primaryButtonBar` when video paused?
I am using media_kit package to display a video. Right now, the controls are hidden where there is no mouse movement for specified controlsHoverDuration. As a workaround, I can set the controlsHoverDuration to a long duration.
MaterialVideoControlsTheme(
  normal: const MaterialVideoControlsThemeData(
    visibleOnMount: true,
    controlsHoverDuration: Duration(hours: 1) // Setting this value to a duration
  ),
  fullscreen: const MaterialVideoControlsThemeData(),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Video(
      controller: controller,
    ),
  ),
);

but that hides the controls when I tap the video.
Another way is to build custom video controls.
Scaffold(
  body: Video(
    controller: _controller,
    controls: (state) {
      return Center(
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            state.widget.controller.player.playOrPause();
          },
          icon: StreamBuilder(
            stream: state.widget.controller.player.stream.playing,
            builder: (context, playing) => Icon(
              playing.data == true ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);

but that requires implementation of all states for a simple requirement. Also I want to stick to MaterialVideoControlsTheme.
Is there a way to always show the play button or primaryButtonBar when the video is in pause state using MaterialVideoControlsTheme?

I also had the same need to display controls without hiding it on tap.
You can create custom controls using Material widgets like for play or pause you can use
MaterialPlayOrPauseButton()
Full Example using material widgets
SizedBox(
  height: 300,
  child: Video(
    controller: controller,
    controls: (state) {
      return const Column(
        children: [
          MaterialPlayOrPauseButton(),
          MaterialSeekBar(),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
);

